# unable to read host from file using python fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have list of IP address stored in hosts_file in my local machine (windows) , running following code to run commands on remote linux servers from windows.

```
def set_hosts():
  env.hosts = open('hosts_file.txt', 'r').readlines() 
  env.user = 'root'
  def display_os():
  run('ls -lart')
```

---

**hosts_file.txt** contains following entries

```
'192.168.56.101'
'192.168.56.102'
```

When I am executing above code getting following error

```
['192.168.56.101'] Executing task 'display_os'
['192.168.56.101'] run: ls -lart

Warning: Name lookup failed for '192.168.56.101'

Underlying exception:
    getaddrinfo failed

['192.168.56.102'] Executing task 'display_os'
['192.168.56.102'] run: ls -lart

Warning: Name lookup failed for '192.168.56.102'

Underlying exception:
    getaddrinfo failed


Done.
```

I have also checked on trailing spaces but not sure why error is thrown.

Comment: What if you remove the quotes in the host file?

Comment: Well Yes ..removed the quote and now code is working fine..Thanks a lot Willene..appreciate your quick help...

Comment: In above code , I am trying to keep single script  ( shell script , powershell )  that will be run on all remote host mentioned in hosts_file. Would you please advise how to do that using fabric...similar to what ansible does

Comment: @user6188245 I think you should post your new question as a separate SO question

Comment: @VadimKotov..I have raised new question with all details